# WTForms SelectField title

Tags: wtforms

In a WTForms SelectField, I want to set a title attribute on each option,
so that hovering the cursor will display that attribute as "balloon help".
Like this:

```
<select name='station'>
  <option title='Thule'>TH</option>
  <option title='Diego Garcia'>DG</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I see that I can iterate over the SelectField to get the
fields.core._Option instances for each choice, I can
store the title text in the .description attribute of each
choice. How do I modify the HTML rendering to use the
.description value as the title attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Show more code to help, but take this samples

```
fieldstation = wtforms.SelectField('station', choices=[("TH", "Thule"), ("DG", "Diego Garcia")])
```

Or something like that

```
fieldstation = wtforms.SelectField(model.Ferris.station._verbose_name, choices=[(t, t.title()) for t in model.Ferris.station._choices])
```